# gcp docker push - permission denied

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

The default service account that a GCP VM use has been granted `storage.buckets.*` and `storage.objects.*` roles yet I get the error that `storage.buckets.create` permission isn't setup.

> denied: Token exchange failed for project 'test-307504'. Caller does
> not have permission 'storage.buckets.create'. To configure
> permissions, follow instructions at:
> https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

The default service account is `123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` and I've created roles related to storage and assigned to the IAM service account and I ran the command `gcloud auth configure-docker`. But still I'm unable to push docker images to the GCR repository.

Is there something else I should be doing after assigning the roles to refresh on the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from permissions, check for the [access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) at the VM level. 
While you are at, read up on [Using the Compute Engine Default Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using_the_default_service_account) and [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#best_practices) too.